# repeat of success class in jquery validation

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="login-form">
                            <form action="page.jsp" id="form-id" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
                                <div> <input type="text" name="Email" id="emaiphys" style="max-width: 320px;"><span id="label-span"></span></div>
                                <input class="btn" type="submit" value="RESET PASSWORD">
                                <a href="./login.jsp">Return to Login</a>
                            </form>
                        </div>
```

I am using jquery validation to validate Email field.Following is my jquery validation code

```
(function($,W,D)
{
    var JQUERY4U = {};

    JQUERY4U.UTIL =
    {
        setupFormValidation: function()
        {
            //form validation rules
            $("#form-id").validate({
               
                errorClass:"errorClass",
                errorElement:"label",
                rules: {
                                Email: {
                                    required: true,
                                    email: true,
                                    remote:"./check-email.jsp"

                                }
                            },
                messages: {
                    Email: {
                        required: "Please enter a Email Address",
                        email: "Please enter a Valid Email Address",
                        remote: "Email not found"
                    }
                },
    highlight:function(element,errorClass){
        $(element).removeClass(errorClass);
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) { 

                //alert(element.parent());
                error.appendTo( element.next()); 
        },
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    form.submit();
                },
    success: function(label) { 
            // set   as text for IE 
            label.addClass('checked');
        } 
            });
        }
    }

    //when the dom has loaded setup form validation rules
    $(D).ready(function($) {
        JQUERY4U.UTIL.setupFormValidation();
    });

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

In case of success a "tick" image is displayed that is defined in a css class.Now if user again enters incorrect email that checked class will still be present and that causes the "tick" image to be visible again incase of error also.So how can that checked class be removed whenever user enters incorect emnail once a correct email has been entered.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another class called

```
.checked.error {
    background-image: none !important;
}
```

This class will be triggered only when both checked and error classes are applied to the label. since we are making the background-image: none !important, it will override the css rule of checked class.

-- Update --

You can try one thing; do not add the checked class to the label, instead add it to the parent div and modify the css rule to target the label in that div eg:

```
success: function(label) { 
    label.closest('div').addClass('checked');
} 

errorPlacement: function(error, element) { 
        element.closest('div').removeClass('checked');
        error.appendTo( element.next()); 
},
```

and the css :

```
.checked .error {
    background-image: none !important;
}
```

Comment: this doesnot work because in case of correct email both checked and error class is added to label..so it will make the tick image to not appear

Comment: i believe in case of correct email, the error class should not be associated with its label.

Comment: jquery automatically adds a error class to the label and if i remove that error class before adding checked class,the tick image gets repeated again and again..so i have to add it

Comment: please have a look at the updates above and let me know if they work.

Comment: does the above updation help?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) { 
            console.log(element); //check if your element is <label> if not use element.find('label')...
            element.removeClass('checked');
            error.appendTo( element.next()); 
    },
```